# react native Component Exception Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple code which I can not get to run, the code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View  } from 'react-native';
import WelcomeScreen from './app/screens/WelcomeScreen.js';

export default function App() {
    return <WelcomeScreen/>
}
```

with the WelcomeScreen.js file being:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from 'react-native'

function WelcomeScreen(props) {
    return (
        <ImageBackground 
            styles={styles.background}
            source={require("../assets/background.png")}
        ></ImageBackground>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        flex: 1
    }
})
```

Each time this is run the console is filled with error messages and upon looking at the app I see the message:
"Component Exception
Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of 'App'."

I'm new to native react but the previous code I had before attempting to import the welcome screen file ran correctly. I've tried to change the default to object in app.js but that didn't work, I've looked around for a while now and just can't figure out what's going on. Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Thank you for your time

Comment: You are not returning anything from `WelcomeScreen.js` ? Like export default WelcomeScreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your Welcome screen to:

```
export default  function WelcomeScreen(props) {
  return (
      <ImageBackground 
          styles={styles.background}
          source={require("../assets/background.png")}
      ></ImageBackground>
  );
}
```

Now you are good to go :)

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to fix that issue however I now get the error "TypeError undefined is not an object (evaluating 'style.width')". Do you know why that may be happening?